# Error generating chart: no features contain non-null values of "DispAlt" - Issue creating a chart in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to create a table in my Google Earth Engine project that populates data based on where the user selects with the cursor.

I converted this code from an example in earth engine and adjusted the variables for my data.  It works when I use data GEE has already loaded into their collection (ie Tigerline data) but it doesn't work with the data I have loaded into the code editor, which is a table from an pelican tracking sensor.

```
var data = table

Map.addLayer(data, null, 'birds', true);

Map.style().set({cursor: 'crosshair'});
// A list of points the user has clicked on, as [lon,lat] tuples.
var selectedPoints = [];

// Returns the list of countries the user has selected.
function getSelectedBirds() {
  return data.filterBounds(ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(selectedPoints));

}

// Makes a table of the given FeatureCollection of countries by name.
function makeResultsTable(data) {

  var newtable = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(data, 'name');
  newtable.setChartType('Table');
  newtable.setOptions({allowHtml: true, pageSize: 5});
  newtable.style().set({stretch: 'both'});
  return newtable;
}
function updateChart() {

  var chart = makeResultsTable(getSelectedBirds());
  resultsPanel.clear().add(chart);
}

function clearResults() {
  selectedPoints = [];
  Map.layers().remove(Map.layers().get(1));
  var instructionsLabel = ui.Label('Select birds to compare altitude.');
  resultsPanel.widgets().reset([instructionsLabel]);
}

// Register a click handler for the map that adds the clicked point to the
// list and updates the map overlay and chart accordingly.
function handleMapClick(location) {
  selectedPoints.push([location.lon, location.lat]);
  //updateOverlay();
  updateChart();
}
Map.onClick(handleMapClick);

// A panel containing the two buttons .
var buttonPanel = ui.Panel(
    [ui.Button('Clear results', clearResults)],
    ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal'), {margin: '0 0 0 auto', width: '500px'});

var resultsPanel = ui.Panel({style: {position: 'bottom-right'}});
Map.add(resultsPanel);
clearResults();nter code here
```

The function `makeResultsTable()` currently spits out the error: `Error generating chart: No features contain non-null values of "name"`.

From the research I have done it seems as though my issue is that GEE is not finding my client-side data inside the function when it's called.  However I'm new to GEE and not very experienced with JavaScript so I'm having a hard time reconciling this issue.

Comment: I just realized I left an old title in the question header, the error that pertains to this particular question is for the value 'name' not 'DispAlt'.  Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Please include a link to a running code editor script, and make sure all your used assets are shared. That makes it easier to help you.